# Make Arc Canvas Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I've two questions the first question is how to make this countdown is responsive. I tried to make this responsive using Bootstrap but I was not able to reach a satisfactory result.

**Note:** You can remove my styles and start from scratch if you want.

---

The second problem is occurred when when I change the radius of the circle from 70 to any other value, that when I change the radius of my countdown circular the circular will be like this:

[image]

[image]

The code is here:

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
    var settings = {
      'date': null
    };
    if (options) {
      $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    this_sel = $(this);
    /*Canvas JavaScript*/
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var canvas3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 90;


    var sec_arc_end = 0,
      min_arc_end = 0,
      hour_arc_end = 0,
      day_arc_end = 0;

    function count_exec() {
      eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
      currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
      if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
        callback.call(this);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

      days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

      seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
      hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
      seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
      minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds -= minutes * 60;

      // seconds arc canvas...................
      context.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      sec_arc_end = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10472));
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + sec_arc_end, false);
      context.lineWidth = 8;
      context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context.stroke();

      // minutes arc canvas...................
      context1.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      min_arc_end = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.10471));
      context1.beginPath();
      context1.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + min_arc_end, false);
      context1.lineWidth = 8;
      context1.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context1.stroke();
        // hours arc canvas...................

      context2.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      hour_arc_end = ((24 - hours) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));
      context2.beginPath();
      context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
      context2.lineWidth = 8;
      context2.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context2.stroke();
        // days arc canvas...................
      if (days > 364) {
          $('#myCanvas3').hide();
      }
      context3.clearRect(50, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      day_arc_end = ((-days) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));  // the problem is here
      context3.beginPath();
      context3.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, -0.5 * Math.PI, (((365 - days) / 365) * 2 - 0.5) * Math.PI, false);
      context3.lineWidth = 8;
      context3.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
      context3.stroke();
      // add 0 value to left of value
      if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
        this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
        this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
        this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
        this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
      }
    }
    count_exec();
    console.log(days);
    interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);


  };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "6 january 2018 6:34:00"
    },
      function () {
          $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
      }
    );
    /*Make Canvas Responsive*/
    $(".countdown-container").height($(".countdown-container").width());
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(".countdown-container").height($(".countdown-container").width());
    });
})
```

```css
#countdown {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.countdown-container {
  width: 24%;
  height: 97%;
  text-align: center;
}
#countdown .countdown-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.30% 0.5% 0.30% 0.5%;
}
#countdown .countdown-container .contents {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size-adjust: 0.58;
}
.contents div {
  font-size: 28px;
}
.contents span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:1px solid #06ee7c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="secs">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Seconds</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="mins">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Minutes</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="hours">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Hours</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="days">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Days</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Note:**

- Please run code in full page
- Wait for 1 minutes that the radius problem is occurred after each session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `clearRect(0,0,width,height)` instead of `clearRect(50,50,width,height)`.

```js
(function($) {
   jQuery.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
     var settings = {
       'date': null
     };
     if (options) {
       $.extend(settings, options);
     }
     this_sel = $(this);
     /*Canvas JavaScript*/
     var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
     var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
     var canvas3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
     var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
     var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
     var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
     var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
     var radius = 90;


     var sec_arc_end = 0,
       min_arc_end = 0,
       hour_arc_end = 0,
       day_arc_end = 0;

     function count_exec() {
       eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
       currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
       if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
         callback.call(this);
         clearInterval(interval);
       }
       seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

       days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

       seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
       hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
       seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
       minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
       seconds -= minutes * 60;

       // seconds arc canvas...................
       context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       sec_arc_end = ((60 - seconds) * parseFloat(0.10472));
       context.beginPath();
       context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + sec_arc_end, false);
       context.lineWidth = 8;
       context.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
       context.stroke();
       // minutes arc canvas...................
       context1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       min_arc_end = ((60 - minutes) * parseFloat(0.10471));
       context1.beginPath();
       context1.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + min_arc_end, false);
       context1.lineWidth = 8;
       context1.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
       context1.stroke();
         // hours arc canvas...................

       context2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       hour_arc_end = ((24 - hours) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));
       context2.beginPath();
       context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 1.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI + hour_arc_end, false);
       context2.lineWidth = 8;
       context2.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
       context2.stroke();
         // days arc canvas...................
       if (days > 364) {
           $('#myCanvas3').hide();
       }
       context3.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       day_arc_end = ((-days) * parseFloat((0.10471 * 5) / 2));  // the problem is here
       context3.beginPath();
       context3.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, -0.5 * Math.PI, (((365 - days) / 365) * 2 - 0.5) * Math.PI, false);
       context3.lineWidth = 8;
       context3.strokeStyle = '#14E170';
       context3.stroke();
       // add 0 value to left of value
       if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
         this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
         this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
         this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
         this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
       }
     }
     count_exec();
     console.log(days);
     interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);


   };
 })(jQuery);
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#countdown").countdown({
         date: "6 january 2018 6:34:00"
     },
       function () {
           $("#countdown").text("merry christmas");
       }
     );
     /*Make Canvas Responsive*/
     $(".countdown-container").height($(".countdown-container").width());
     $(window).resize(function () {
         $(".countdown-container").height($(".countdown-container").width());
     });
 })
```

```css
#countdown {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.countdown-container {
  width: 24%;
  height: 97%;
  text-align: center;
}
#countdown .countdown-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.30% 0.5% 0.30% 0.5%;
}
#countdown .countdown-container .contents {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size-adjust: 0.58;
}
.contents div {
  font-size: 28px;
}
.contents span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:1px solid #06ee7c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown">
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="secs">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Seconds</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="mins">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Minutes</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="hours">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Hours</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="days">
                    00
                </div>
                <span>Days</span>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This article you linked to and by extend your answer, are misleading. [`closePath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath) as nothing to do wit Path declaration. This is just a `lineTo(lastMovedPoint.x, lastMovedPoint.y)`. This absolutely don't tell the context that we are starting a new Path declaration. Only `beginPath` *and some other hacks you don't wanna use* do so.

Comment: Now that you've removed the link, only your answer is misleading ;-) **You didn't fixed OP's code by this `closePath` call**. You did so by changing `clearRect(50,50,width,height)` to `clearRect(0,0,width,height)`...

Comment: @Kaiido you are right i just run and it did not work.I'll update the answer.